# Check if object contains array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if my `object` contain `array`? for example:

```
let object1 = {
    name:'abc',
    items:[
        {item_name:'123'},
        {item_name:'456'}
    ]
}
```

Imagine `object1` is coming from server and I am not sure that it will or will not (or even have more) array in it. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean check if it has that specific `items` array in it? Or just any array?

Comment: How deep does it need to check? For example, does this object contain an array ~ `{ foo: { bar: [1,2,3] } }`?

Comment: I fail to see how this question has garnered two upvotes. It contains ambiguous requirements and zero research effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to iterate and determine if any value is an array.

```js
let object1 = {
    name:'abc',
    items:[{item_name:'123'},{item_name:'456'}]
}

let res = Object.values(object1).some((val) => Array.isArray(val));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

with [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

> The [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method determines whether the passed value is an Array.

```js
let object1 = {
  name:'abc',
  items:[
    {item_name:'123'},
    {item_name:'456'}
  ]
}

var r = Object.keys(object1).some(i => Array.isArray(object1[i]));
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** and [**Array.isArray**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```js
let object1 = {name:'abc',items:[{item_name:'123'},{item_name:'456'}]}

let op = Object.values(object1).some(e=>Array.isArray(e))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: At least when your answer was using `Object.keys`, it was different to the other answers

Comment: @Phil i realized that in this case using values is a better. because we need to access values any how

Answer (score 1):

Use `isArray()`. It tells if an object is an array or not. [Refer](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp)

```js
let object1 = {
name:'abc',
items:[
{item_name:'123'},
{item_name:'456'}
]
}
Object.values(object1).forEach((e)=>{
if(Array.isArray(e))
{
console.log('true')
}})
```

Comment: FYI: Returning from the `forEach` callback does nothing. This will once again perform unnecessary comparisons after finding the first array

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `isArray` on `Object.values`, then convert `length` to `Boolean`:

```js
let object1 = {
  name:'abc',
  items:[
    {item_name:'123'},
    {item_name:'456'}
  ]
}

console.log(Boolean(Object.values(object1).find(e => Array.isArray(e)).length));
```